# ActiveRecord - group records with the same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

let's say I have a table "foo". it has a column "bar". the type of bar is integer, but ***I can't know how many values there are in advance***.

I want to group the records according to the value of `bar`. records with the same "bar" value should be contained in an array. All of such arrays should be contained in another array.

what I want to do is

```
Foo.all
=> [#<Foo id: 1, bar: 1>, #<Foo id: 2, bar: 1>, #<Foo id: 3, bar: 2>, #<Foo id: 4, bar: 3>]
Foo.group_records_with_the_same_value("bar")
=> [[#<Foo id: 1, bar: 1>, #<Foo id: 2, bar: 1>], [#<Foo id: 3, bar: 2>], [#<Foo id: 4, bar: 3>]
```

what's the most elegant way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
h = Foo.all.group_by { |x| x.bar }
h.each {|key, value| value.each {|foo| puts foo['bar'] }}
```

`group_by` will return a hash, **not** an array. however, hash is better than array in many situations, so I don't think it's a disadvantage.